# How to produce a depth(height) image from mesh with opengl or dx

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, directx

Now I have a mesh(.off), and I want to project the mesh to a plane, to get a 
gray-scale image.

The pixels in the image represent the depth(may be positive or negative) from the points in mesh model to the plane,and (x,y) in the image is the same in mesh.(notice:not only project the vertices but also the faces and edges,we can use interpolation or so).

Any one get ideas? Or any currently available code?

Answer (score 3):

With OpenGL, you can start by drawing your mesh. Then use `glReadPixels`, specifying `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` to read back the depth for the pixels. One minor detail: the values you get will be mapped to the range 0..1 so you almost always want to use a floating point type (e.g., `GL_FLOAT`).

If you *really* need that converted to distances from your mesh to the plane, you'll need to find the minimum and maximum distances, and use linear interpolation to convert the pixel values back to distances. For most purposes (including a grey-scale image) the 0..1 range works fine without further transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your useful advice.So I have to write linear interpolation by myself? Can openGL do it automatically? I do not know how to interpolate a point in a face.

Comment: You need to find the point closest to the plane and the point farthest from the plane in your mesh. Then each pixel's distance will be `nearest + pixel_value * (farthest-nearest)`.

Comment: the distances you will read from a raw depth buffer are not linear, you will need to reverse the projection formula to get the world depth.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a modern solution to go by pixel reading, what you want to do for production code, is render to texture using a pixel shader that output depth. then you can decide if you want to output homogeneous depth, linear depth, spherical depth, world depth of whatever depth you want !

this kind of solution can be executed in real time (one time per frame) if necessary.
your output texture could be `byte R8` or `float R16` or even `float R32` if you need (careful about performance problems due to bandwidth restrictions on low end graphic cards though).

the homogenous depth would just be to pass the world position as you output it from your vertex shader as a varying into your pixel shader (in a texcoord), then in the pixel shader outputs the z of that vector. You need to remember that this vector has been divided by its w component by the rasterizer between the vertex shader and pixel shader. This method gets your the `homogeneous depth`, which is not linear and is the same result that you would get reading the depth buffer directly.

then you can also output the world depth, or the lienar depth, by passing a vector with "1" in its w component as a varying.

you could output a spherical depth, which makes a difference when using perspective projections. the spherical depth is the real raytraced depth using a length function. you get this value by taking the length of the vector `world coordinate of my pixel -> eye position`. eye position is the 4th row of your view matrix (passed as uniform). And `world coordinate of my pixel` is a value interpolated by the rasterizer from the varyings exited from the vertex shader (the same than the linear depth, with 1 in the w). This one needs to be output in a floating point texture format otherwise you'll get a lot of clamping and precision problems.

now that you have your render target rendered, you can use the texture in a second stage of the rendering by plugging it as a sampler in another shader later.
Or you can stream it back to CPU using `CopyResource` to a `staged` memory managed second texture that you can then `map` or `lock` and then simply memcpy to CPU memory. careful that this kind of process kills the framerate and should be avoided, or done rarely for example for screen shots, or debugging.